# No music in Hotline Miami 1 on Mac

Tags: macos, hotline-miami

I bought Hotline Miami 1, and while the game works just fine, music is not working (100% volume - no music, sound effects work fine). As the soundtrack is so integral to the game, it would be a shame to play without it.

I'm using OS X 10.9.5, I can't seem to find any solutions online, and OSX' Error Console is not throwing any clues either. Any ideas how I could go about fixing this problem?

Comment: Are you saying other sounds are working but the music isn't?

Comment: Yes. I can hear weapon sounds just fine, but no music at all (not even during startup/in menus).

Comment: Hey, I got my copy of Steam. System Version: OS X 10.10.3 (14D136). I have all the sound, music, weapon sounds. Everything is working great. Why not upgrade to Yosemite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting the game (*Hotline Miami JPN Update OSX*) in **Original** instead of **Updated** Mode, selectable in the start screen, has fixed the problem.